# Splitting up the directive's controller into smaller parts

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

So I've made this Plunker that works well as a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zm9d6zHhrnqDlnJsSZ1I?p=preview . It's a simple pagination with two attribute arguments that holds the model-state and some config-state. I want to end up with a directive factory like this (or something explaining how to reason differently):

```
angular.module('mnPagination').factory(function(model, config) {
  return {
    model: model,
    config: config
  }
})
```

My issue with the current plunker is that the app layer and the directive layer doesn't look alike. Since I only have one app I can use factories as singleton data providers. That's really good!

But inside the directive, I can't use any kind of provider since it will be a singleton. The scope is a new object for every declared instance so that's the only place I can put any stateful code that should be contained in the directive.

Are directives supposed to be stateless?

Another more meta question: Am I the only one freaking out about this?

It's my second SO attempt, and noone on facebook or at work are really that into MVVM/MVC or directives with isolated scope.

I'm Leya, come be my Luke!

Comment: I am wondering if the ability to access the scopes parent from the directive's controller might help? Not sure how clean that would be though.

Comment: I am trying to understand your question. Splitting the controller into smaller parts: is this about creating "Controller Helpers" or "functionality pieces" to aggregate together? Can you elaborate on this a little (I am curious, this might be useful for me).

Comment: @user1441287: Parent scope access would be contraproductive for me. I want as much separation as possible so I can easily replace code and easier understand my code without looking into the parent scope.

Comment: @Bernhard: Yes, either one of those since I quite don't understand the angular team's design of directives and providers. But I love the idea to be able to use an aggregate of functionality that can be used with the dependency injection system. That means I could easily share models without views for stuff like calendars. But to be fair the question could be answered with a composite solution instead of an aggregate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way I solved this was by creating a factory inside an angular factory.

```
angular.module('mnPagination').factory('mnPaginationFactory', function() {
  var factory = function (items, config) {
    ...
  }

  return factory
}
```

Now I get a new object for each directive by calling the factory from the controller which has the items and config objects on the scope.

Plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/DPTZUjeMihsva5nJ3IVx?p=preview .

Comment: My first reaction to this double-factory is that you are rolling-your-own-factory-system and working around the injector's providers system. I mean, why not use .provider( { $get: function } ). It might do the multiple instance trick you are seeking.  DISCLAIMER: I have not tested this and I could be wrong, this is inferred from the docs.

From the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#provider

_"Object: then it should have a $get method. The $get method will be invoked using $injector.invoke() when an instance needs to be created."_

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but the provider.$get is only called once so I think I have to create a new $injector for every directive instance or call the provider.$get multiple times somehow.
What I've seen in .NET DI-systems, you can setup the injector to give back a new instance every time or just a singleton. I'm missing that choice right now.